# EmguCV/OpenCV images fusion and GPU (CUDA)

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am using EmguCV + CUDA to do some operations on image (detections).

My both images overlap each other. I am using my own algorithm to do this. The idea is:

- the first image is at the left, the second to the right. One part of these images overlap.
  [image]
  [image]
- To do the overlap part I use the fusion of each pixel. At the left, the first image 1 is more important (alpha1 = 1, alpha2 = 0), at the extrem right we have the opposite (alpha1 = 0, alpha2 = 1), at the middle alpha1 = 0.5, alpha2 = 0.5. The result :
  [image]

My source code :

```
int start = (int)Math.Min(Math.Min(corners[0].X, corners[1].X), Math.Min(corners[2].X, corners[3].X));
Double processWidth = image1.Width - start; // The overlap size

for (int i = 0; i < image1.Width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image1.Height; j++)
    {
        double alphaImg = 1;
        double alphaDest = 0;
        if (i >= start)
        {
            alphaImg = (processWidth - (i - start)) / processWidth;
            alphaDest = 1 - alphaImg;
        }

        Gray colorImg = image1[j, i];
        byte colorDest = imageFinal.GetValue(j, i);

        double b = (1 - alphaDest) * alphaImg + alphaDest;
        int colorNew = (int)(((1 - alphaDest) * alphaImg * colorImg.Intensity + alphaDest * colorDest) / b);
        if (colorDest == 0)
            colorNew = (int)colorImg.Intensity;

        imageFinal.SetValue(j, i, (byte)colorNew);
    }
}
```

The code is working but is slow. Do you know if there is a better do to this with some OpenCV/CUDA functions ?

The source article of the algorithm: https://www.programmersought.com/article/67251192193/

Comment: The algorithm can be translated into Cuda nearly 1:1. Initialize CUDA. Alloc memory. Copy memory to device. Call cuda kernel ('kernels' are Cuda functions). Copy back result. Clean up. It is well parallelizable with the two for loops. What would be your specific questions?

Comment: Do you know CUDA C++? Can you use it?

Comment: Call cudaFunction<<<(width * height + 255) / 256, 256>>>(params); inside cudaFunction use: int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; int i = tid % width; int j = tid / width; Replace GetValue and SetValue with direct accesses to device memory (e.g. unsigned char with 3 bytes per pixel) with index [3 * (width * j + i) + 0]; and the same for + 1 and + 2

Comment: Thank you. Currently I have anoters problemes to solved bu I keep this optimisations in my head.
I do not know how to directly use Cuda from C#. I will ahve to do some training.

Comment: @JonathanLeCornichone It is not easy, you can use Hybridizer, which I don't recommend, or write a dll in C++ that use CUDA, then use it into C#, I did this before and it worked.

Comment: managedCuda seems to be another possibility

Comment: When I test your code it gives me a blue image. Can you link your code so I could better take a look at it?